# Error while loading data from csv to table using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc, pandas-datareader, pysqlite

I am having the csv file, when I am trying to load CSV to the table using pandas dataframe I am getting an error please help me

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\PYTHON\csv.csv")
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
                      'Server=SIS10647\MSSQLSERVER14;'
                      'Database=LeelaVenkatesh;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO pandas(NAME,DEPART,COLUM) values (?,?,?)", row.NAME, row.DEPART, row.COLUM)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

iam getting following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lrangu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/PANDAS.py", line 10, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO pandas(NAME,DEPART,COLUM) values (?,?,?)", row.NAME, row.DEPART, row.COLUM)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=numpy.int64', 'HY105')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error that you got:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type. param-index=0
> param-type=numpy.int64', 'HY105')

Some of the elements in the parameters (`row.NAME`, `row.DEPART`, `row.COLUM`) are `numpy.int64` that can not be used directly as a parameter for the SQL statement. So, ***you need to make sure that all of the parameters are in the correct and supported type*** before you execute the SQL statement.

### SOLUTION

Specify the datatype as `Int64`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\PYTHON\csv.csv", dtype="Int64")
```

Comment: Since all are integer datatype but still is not coming 
even i tried row[0],row[1],row[2] still the same

Comment: Have you tried the integer like 1, 2, 3? Was it worked?

Comment: It is weired. Can you try to specify the datatype of the columns when you read csv as `Int64`

Comment: Can you please help me where i have to sppecify

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226078/discussion-between-chanukya-and-jaypeerachai).